# BitLocker encrypted Win 10 computers report version 7

Tags: windows-10, bitlocker

I use the Powershell command:

> manage-bde -status -cn COMPUTERNAME

to remotely check the Bitlocker status of laptops on our network.

It has suddently struck me that all of the Windows 10 machines report back (OS drive C):

> "BitLocker Version: Windows 7"

Why is this?

**>>UPDATE:**

I have now tried this locally instead of remotely and the same machine reports "BitLocker Version: 2.0"
This laptop has a TPM 1.2.

Comment: What version of Windows was used to encrypt the storage device?

Comment: They were all encrypted stand-alone in their host machine, so 10.

Comment: From what I've seen, the version of BitLocker used for FDE in W10 is the same as the one used in W7.  Hence a "BitLocker Version" of W7.  The Operating System version is still W10, it is just the BL version you're looking at.

Comment: While I think @Ruscul is probably right.  Which exact version of Windows 10 are you using?  I'm on 1607, and it reports "BitLocker Version: 2.0"

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 - That does not make sense.  The only thing I can think is that version value is connect to either TPM 2.0 or (software) i.e. Windows rather then the version of Bitlocker specifically

Comment: @ramhound I'm thinking that he may be running an older version that hadn't had its BitLocker exe updated since Windows 7 here

Comment: @ramhound But your TPM theory may be right. I have TPM 2.0 available on my system.

Comment: As an example one of the machines reporting this is Win 10 enterprise 1607

Comment: have you selected to encrypt whole drive or only used space. used space is new, maybe the whole drive encryption is reported as old win7 one.

Comment: It is whole drive encryption yes. None of these machines have ever had 7 on them though.

Comment: ok, this is the answer. full encryption is the win7 style.

Comment: So, please post an answer, somebody?